# Pattern to validate PDF and Excel file type

Tags: java, excel, pdf, pattern-matching, arrays

I have a web-app that allows users to upload attachments; however, I want to limit the user to only certain file types - Adobe PDF and MS Excel.
The reason being is just before the user submits the document for processing and workflow, I will aggregate some of the attachments and create a single PDF report.

I did some research and converting DOC(X), RTF, etc... would be headache.
Plus everybody will "in theory" get better viewing portability if the attachments are all in PDF.

Currently I am checking the mime type -

PDF - `"application/pdf"`

XLS(X) -

- `"application/vnd.ms-excel"`
- `"application/msexcel"`
- `"application/x-msexcel"`
- `"application/x-ms-excel"`
- `"application/x-excel"`
- `"application/x-dos_ms_excel"`
- `"application/xls"`
- `"application/x-xls"`

This is working well, except I've noticed that I can take for instance a `.docx` file and change it's extension to `.pdf` and successfully get around this check.

To remedy that, I plan to further check the actual file's header.

According to [this library](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) of file signatures

PDF will have the following header -

`25 50 44 46`

AND it will have one of the following trailers -

- `0A 25 25 45 4F 46 (.%%EOF)`
- `0A 25 25 45 4F 46 0A (.%%EOF.)`
- `0D 0A 25 25 45 4F 46 0D 0A (..%%EOF..)`
- `0D 25 25 45 4F 46 0D (.%%EOF.)`

So far I have the skeleton code that will perform this check -

** EDITED TO REFLECT ANSWER **

```
public boolean confirmAttachmentAuthenticity(ProposalDevelopmentForm form, String mimeType) {
    boolean authentic = true;
    // Case:  User is attempting to upload a "PDF" document
    if (mimeType.equals(ADOBE_PDF_CONTENT_TYPE)) {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = form.getNewNarrative().getNarrativeFile().getInputStream();
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputStream);
            int numberOfPages = pdfReader.getNumberOfPages();
            if (numberOfPages > 0) {
                // Success - valid PDF
                info(form.getNewNarrative().getNarrativeFile().getFileName() + " validated authentic Adobe PDF file");
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ioe) {
            // Failure - masquerading PDF
            authentic = false;
            info(form.getNewNarrative().getNarrativeFile().getFileName() + " is not an authentic Adobe PDF file.");
            reportError("newNarrative.narrativeFile",
                KeyConstants.ERROR_ATTACHMENT_PDF_NOT_AUTHENTIC,
                form.getNewNarrative().getNarrativeFile().getFileName());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // Failure - other causes
            authentic = false;
            info(form.getNewNarrative().getNarrativeFile().getFileName() + " could not be authenticated at this time.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            reportError("newNarrative.narrativeFile",
                KeyConstants.ERROR_ATTACHMENT_TYPE_CORRUPTED,
                form.getNewNarrative().getNarrativeFile().getFileName());
        }
    }
    // Case: User is attempting to upload an "EXCEL" spreadsheet
    else {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = form.getNewNarrative().getNarrativeFile().getInputStream();
            POIFSFileSystem fileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(inputStream);
            HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileSystem);
            int numberOfSheets = workBook.getNumberOfSheets();
            if (numberOfSheets > 0) {
                // Success - valid Excel Spreadsheet
                info(form.getNewNarrative().getNarrativeFile().getFileName() + " validated authentic MS Excel file");
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ioe) {
            // Failure - masquerading XLS(X)
            authentic = false;
            info(form.getNewNarrative().getNarrativeFile().getFileName() + " is not an authentic MS Excel file.");
            reportError("newNarrative.narrativeFile",
                KeyConstants.ERROR_ATTACHMENT_XLS_NOT_AUTHENTIC,
                form.getNewNarrative().getNarrativeFile().getFileName());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // Failure - other causes
            authentic = false;
            info(form.getNewNarrative().getNarrativeFile().getFileName() + " could not be authenticated at this time.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            reportError("newNarrative.narrativeFile",
                    KeyConstants.ERROR_ATTACHMENT_TYPE_CORRUPTED,
                    form.getNewNarrative().getNarrativeFile().getFileName());
        }
    }
    return authentic;
}
```

I'm thinking the best approach would be use the `BinarySearch` method to do this.
But, I've also read some posts where people have suggested converting the fileData into a string and then using regular expressions.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Bonus points if you can help me start filling in my skeleton code for either case.
My bit-wise logic knowledge is rusty.  That's what I get for coding mostly high level client side code for the past year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do **never** trust incoming requests from clients, headers values could be changed and it doesn't reflect what is in the body of the request .

use instead a third parties libraries to check if the file is a PDF or Excel or something else.

to check if a document is a PDF try for example to open it using [iText](http://itextpdf.com/), and for Excel try to open it using  [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/).

Comment: I have updated the code segment above in the question to reflect the answer provided by @Mifmif. This is the code that solved the problem of verifying the 2 file types my web-app will accept.